# Динамическая подгрузка видео/аудио с сервера, когда пользователь досмотрел/дослушал до определенного момента

Tags: javascript, golang, аудио, видео, соцсети

Пытаюсь написать свою соц сеть. В современных соц сетях и на видеоплатформах реализована функция, когда аудио и видео контент отдается сервером не полностью, а подзагружается "по требованию". Как такое реализовать со стороны клиента и сервера? Использую браузерный js на клиенте и golang на сервере.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш вопрос довольно обширный, и однозначного ответа тут скорее всего
нет.  Есть несколько технологий потокового видео, например
[*MPEG-DASH*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Adaptive_Streaming_over_HTTP)
или
[*HLS*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming),
а также множество проприетарных протоколов.  У всех свои преимущества
и недостатки.  Выбрав что-то, что подходит вам, найти или создать свою
имплементацию этого дела на стороне сервера
и клиента — дело недолгое.